# Sum of previous rows in a column R

Tags: r, roc

I have table as following

```
id State
1 True
2 False
3 True
4 False
5 False
6 True
7 True
8 False
```

I need to count true and false until showed row . So the result should be as the following table

```
id State  Yes   No
1 True      1   0
2 False     1   1
3 True      2   1
4 False     2   2
5 False     2   3
6 True      3   3
7 True      4   3
8 False     4   4
```

Until 6th(including 6th) row there are 3 False and 3 True. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
df$yes <- cumsum(df$State == "True")
df$no <- cumsum(df$State == "False")
```

Or if you have df$State as a logical vector

```
df$yes <- cumsum(df$State)
df$no <- cumsum(!df$State)
```

Comment: as suggested by @akrun `df$yes <- cumsum(as.logical(df$State))` and `df$no <- cumsum(!as.logical(df$State))` should work better.. :)

Comment: @G.Cocca  The `as.logical` based on the `'State'` column may not work as the values are `"True"` and `"False"`

Comment: I assumed that `as.logical` coerces its argument (in this case factor or character) to be of logical type, resulting in a vector of class logical.. What is/are the case where it might not work?

Comment: as.logical("True") works fine despite the capital case.